# How to set time with seconds and without date and timezone in PSQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, psql

I have a problem with pslq database when I connect it with C# application. When I fill the datagridview with data from PSQL database, I get this type of data:

[image]

What I need is type of time: `HH:mm:ss` ONLY, so for ex. in this case: `08:48:00`.
Can someone tell me what type of data I need to set that column to in PSQL database?

P.S. My database column that I fill datagridview with looks like this in PSQL database:

[image]

Data type in PSQL for that column:

[image]

Comment: the data in db looks as you want. Look into datagridview instead

Comment: Depending on how you actually fill your grid you are missing a `StringFormat`, or a `String.Format`. A [mcve] would definitely help here.